# rake task: Undefined method for Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I have added a new task to my RakeFile (I know the new way of doing it is to add your task to lib/tasks, but other tasks are in the RakeFile and I dont wish to refactor just yet.) The task that I added accesses a model (maybe not though as the model name is not in the error) but wont access its method.

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `transcode' for #<Class:0x10700e878>
```

My task in the RakeFile is pretty simple;

```
namespace :casta do
  desc "Transcode user videos from S3"
  task :transcode => :environment do
    ProfileVideo.transcode
  end
end
```

And my model is as simple as it gets;

```
class ProfileVideo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :application_form

  def transcode
    puts "Transcoding"
  end

end
```

My other RakeFile tasks use script/runner and they work perfectly fine.

rails 2.3.14
rake 0.8.7 (I was on 0.9.2 though downgraded to test)

Would love some insight, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling transcode as a class method, so change the transcode method to:

```
  def self.transcode
    puts "Transcoding"
  end
```

Or more likely what you want: you can create an instance of ProfileVideo and call transcode on that, and leave the transcode method as it is:

```
  task :transcode => :environment do
    pv = ProfileVideo.new(attributes)
    pv.transcode
  end
```

Comment: Shoots and scores! Perfect! Thanks very much!

Comment: Oh, I really like the second option actually, perfect.